# python to add list and string in header in csv file

Tags: python-3.x

```
a=[]

    for i in range(9216):

        a.append("pixel"+str(i))

    with open('train41.csv', 'w') as csvfile:

        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=["label",a])
        writer.writeheader()
```

this is not working

I want to add a string label along with the list a in my csv file header

Answer (score 0):

`fieldnames` must be a list of strings:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=["label"] + a)
```

You used a list with one string and another list of strings:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=["label",a])
```